# add tags to auto inserted joomla article?

Tags: joomla

I used [this tutorial](https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/204-using-the-joomla-api-to-add-articles-programmatically) for adding some Joomla article.

It works and Joomla article are there, but how I can add some Joomla tags to that articles programmatically?

There is a helper (jhelpertags) that have a function for add contentTagmaps, but I don't know how I can use that.

Comment: i use DBO object to add some rows in contenttag_maps table manually, and in joomla article editor, there is my added tags to that content, but when i click on tag name in site front-end, my auto maped articles not shown!!, i have to open article in backend and just save and close it to work!